# How to insert looping data in Oracle Database using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, oracle, oracle11g

```
 Dim cmd = New OracleCommand

    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

        Sql = "INSERT INTO TM_EMPLOYEE_INFO (V_EMPLOYEE_NO, "
        Sql = Sql & "V_NAME_TRAINEE,N_GENDER,V_COMPANY) "
        Sql = Sql & " VALUES('" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & "', "
        Sql = Sql & "'" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value & "', "
        Sql = Sql & "'" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value & "', "
        Sql = Sql & "'" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value & "') "

    Next

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Using connection As New OracleConnection("Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source = XE;User ID = MAN_HOUR;Password = FDTP_MAN_HOUR;")
        Dim command As New OracleCommand(Sql)
        command.Connection = connection
        Try
            connection.Open()
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Using
```

This is my code. I thinks its already okay but when I run the program the vshost.exe message box appeared. Please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: * HOW TO INSERT LOOPING DATA IN ORACLE DATABASE USING VB.NET *

Comment: Instead of adding a comment, just edit your title and post as necessary.

Comment: ...and what did the *vshost.exe message box* say?

Comment: That code is deeply flawed.  For a start, you have two different `OracleCommand` objects in there and you're calling `ExecuteNonQuery` on both with the first one never having its `CommandText` or `Connection` properties set.

Comment: Secondly, you are getting the data from the rows in a loop and doing nothing useful with it.  You build a SQL string and then simply discard it without using it on the next iteration.  You don't actually use the SQL string until the loop has ended so all but the last row will not be saved.

Comment: Thirdly, you're using string concatenation to build SQL from user input which raises all sorts of issues, including a major security flaw.  You should be using parameters to insert values into SQL code.

Comment: Finally, if you intend to save the data to a database, why don;t you have a `DataTable` bound to the grid in the first place?  Then you'd only have to make one call to `Update` on an `OracleDataAdapter`.  If not that then at least populate a `DataTable` in your loop and then save using an adapter.

Answer (score 0):

When you use provider `OraOLEDB.Oracle` you must use `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand`. Otherwise you have to use provider `Oracle.DataAccess`.

Then you must execute the insert inside the loop, not outside. Would be like this:

```
  Using connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source = XE;User ID = MAN_HOUR;Password = FDTP_MAN_HOUR;")
     connection.Open()

     Dim command As New OleDbCommand()
     command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
     command.Connection = connection

     For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Sql = "INSERT INTO TM_EMPLOYEE_INFO (V_EMPLOYEE_NO, "
        Sql = Sql & "V_NAME_TRAINEE,N_GENDER,V_COMPANY) "
        Sql = Sql & " VALUES('" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & "', "
        Sql = Sql & "'" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value & "', "
        Sql = Sql & "'" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value & "', "
        Sql = Sql & "'" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value & "') "
        command.CommandText = Sql
        Try
           command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
           Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
     Next
     connection.Close()
  End Using
```

However, this is a bad implementation, better work with bind variables like this:

```
  Using connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source = XE;User ID = MAN_HOUR;Password = FDTP_MAN_HOUR;")
     connection.Open()

     Dim command As New OleDbCommand()
     command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
     command.Connection = connection
     Sql = "INSERT INTO TM_EMPLOYEE_INFO "
     Sql = Sql & "(V_EMPLOYEE_NO, V_NAME_TRAINEE,N_GENDER,V_COMPANY) "
     Sql = Sql & "VALUES (?,?,?,?)"

     command.CommandText = Sql
     command.Parameters.Add("empNo", OleDbType.Integer)
     command.Parameters.Add("trainee", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
     command.Parameters.Add("gender", OleDbType.VarChar, 10)
     command.Parameters.Add("company", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)

     For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        For c = 0 To 4
           command.Parameters(c).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(c).Value
        Next
        Try
           command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
           Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
     Next
     connection.Close()
  End Using
```